# How to update excel input file directly in Azure Git repository without downloading the entire project folder to local machine

Tags: excel, git, azure-devops

I have a java maven project (Eclipse) in Azure Git repository.
It is a test project to create data in system based on the input given in the excel.
Currently I have the entire project cloned in local machine with git, update the input excel file and push to Azure repository, before running the test.
Is there a way to push changes to the input excel file directly in repository, without downloading the entire project folder to local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upload it directly ...

[image: Upload]

... naturally, it will create a commit but this is easy enough.  I've made code changes before without an IDE by simply editing existing files in the repo online.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the easiest option to download and upload the updated version directly to git. I tried this and it works. thank you

Answer (score 1):

We have no method to directly open and edit an Excel file in Git repository on the web browser.

I have tried on several Git-based version control platforms (Azure Git Repos, GutHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, etc..). None of then can allow users to directly open and edit an Excel file in Git repository.

I also did not find any available extension can help to do this.

So, you need to download the Excel file to the local where the MS Office installed, then open and edit it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, using the [Azure DevOps Services REST / Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-a-binary-file)

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=6.0
```

But that seems a lot of work compared to a simple script which would, every time you have modified locally your Excel file:

- `git add`
- `git commit`
- `git push`

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST and Powershell to update files on remote repo.... as an example:

```
$user = ""
$token = "<PAT>" #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<org>"
$teamProject = "TestProject"
$repoName = "Repo1"

$localFilePath = 'c:/temp/tst.xlsx'
$gitFilePath = 'testfolder/tst.xlsx'
$gitBranch = "master"

$restApiUpdateFile = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/pushes?api-version=6.1-preview.2"
$restApiGetMasterRef = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/refs?filter=heads/$gitBranch`&api-version=6.1-preview.1"

$fileContentToUpdate = [convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content -path $localFilePath -Encoding byte))

function InvokeGetRequest ($GetUrl)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}    
}

function InvokePostRequest ($PostUrl, $body)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Body $body
}

$updateBody = @"
{
    "refUpdates": [
      {
        "name": "refs/heads/{gitbranchpath}",
        "oldObjectId": "{mainBranchObjectId}"
      }
    ],
    "commits": [
      {
        "comment": "Updates file",
        "changes": [
          {
            "changeType": "edit",
            "item": {
              "path": "{filePathToUpdate}"
            },
            "newContent": {
              "content": "{newFileContentToUpdate}",
              "contentType": "base64encoded"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
"@

$res = InvokeGetRequest $restApiGetMasterRef

$updateBody = $updateBody.Replace("{gitbranchpath}", $gitBranch);
$updateBody = $updateBody.Replace("{mainBranchObjectId}", $res.value[0].objectId);
$updateBody = $updateBody.Replace("{filePathToUpdate}", $gitFilePath);
$updateBody = $updateBody.Replace("{newFileContentToUpdate}", $fileContentToUpdate);


InvokePostRequest $restApiUpdateFile $updateBody
```

Comment: This might be a solution to my question. But I really don't have any idea of this code or how and when to run. Downloading the file and upload the updated file seems to be the easiest option for my requirement.  Thank you